# Checking if a TCP port is closed with monit

Tags: monit

I would like to check that a defined port on a host is closed, for example the *8080* port on host *www.example.com*. I tried something like:

```
check host www.example.com with address www.example.com
    if not failed 8080 protocol http then alert
```

but I think I cannot use that syntax because the **not** keyword is not allowed there:

```
/etc/monit/conf.d/myhost:29: Error: syntax error 'failed'
```

Is there any way to do that without writing an external script?

Answer (score 0):

Use `if succeeded`

```
# Verify that port 22, 80 and 443 is open and that port 8000 is closed
check host myhost with address localhost
  if failed port 22 then alert
  if failed port 80 then alert
  if failed port 443 then alert
  if succeeded port 8000 then alert
```

Answer (score -1):

The following Monit check will attempt connect to server www.example.com on port 8080 using TCP.

```
if failed host www.example.com port 8080 then alert
```

If the connection operation fails Monit generates an error and performs an action, it sends an alert in this case.

This is how the above looks in the monit log:

`error    : socket_create: Could not create socket -- Operation now in progress
error    : 'portCheckTest' failed, cannot open a connection to INET[www.example.com:8080] via TCP`